# symfony cmf doctrine phpcr migrator page variable

Tags: doctrine, symfony-cmf

im following the symfony [cmf tutorial](http://symfony.com/pdf/Symfony_cmf_master.pdf?v=3), i setup an mysql connection instead of sql_light. i setup the database, but now im trying to add the the page with the command from the tutorial:

```
php app/console doctrine:phpcr:migrator page --identifier=/cms/simple/test
```

but this gives the following error

```
 [InvalidArgumentException]                      
  Wrong value 'page' for migrator_name argument.  
  Available migrators:                            

doctrine:phpcr:migrator:migrate [--identifier[="..."]] [--depth[="..."]] [--session[="..."]] [migrator_name]
```

What do i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just want to share my experience.
[Symfony-cmf-standard](https://github.com/symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf-standard)
follow tutorial there.

before following this command

```
app/console doctrine:database:create 
app/console doctrine:phpcr:init:dbal 
app/console doctrine:phpcr:register-system-node-types 
app/console doctrine:phpcr:fixtures:load
```

change you db configuration bia web/config.php or parameters.yml

on windows,

```
app/console doctrine:phpcr:fixtures:load
```

may fail, you can follow this link [windows fix](https://github.com/phpcr/phpcr-utils/pull/51)

good luck,