# Fatal error installing Symfony CMF

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-cmf

I'm trying to install Symfony CMF but I'm getting the following error while creating the database:

> Fatal error: Class 'PHPCR\Util\Console\Command\MoveCommand' not found
>   in
>   /vendor/doctrine/phpcr-bundle/Doctrine/Bundle/PHPCRBundle/Command/NodeMoveCommand.php
>   on line 34

My composer.json is as follows:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.2.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "2.3.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.4.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.3.*",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "*",
        "sonata-project/user-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
        "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle" : "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
        "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "dev-master",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "1.1.x-dev",
        "sonata-project/block-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",


        "jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/phpcr-bundle": "1.0.*@dev",
        "doctrine/phpcr-odm": "1.0.*@dev"


    },
```

AppKernel:

```
    // App bundles
    new Application\Sonata\UserBundle\ApplicationSonataUserBundle(),

    // Vendor bundles
    new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
    new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),

    new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
    new JMS\AopBundle\JMSAopBundle(),
    new JMS\DiExtraBundle\JMSDiExtraBundle($this),
    new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle(),



    new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
    new Sonata\jQueryBundle\SonatajQueryBundle(),
    new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),
    new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),
    new Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle(),
    new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),
    new Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle('FOSUserBundle'),
    new Sonata\EasyExtendsBundle\SonataEasyExtendsBundle(),

    new Doctrine\Bundle\PHPCRBundle\DoctrinePHPCRBundle(),
```

I have the following line setup in autoload.php

```
AnnotationRegistry::registerFile(__DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine/phpcr-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/PHPCR/Mapping/Annotations/DoctrineAnnotations.php');
```

And finally my config.yml relevant section:

```
doctrine_phpcr:
    session:
        backend:
            type: doctrinedbal
            connection: doctrine.dbal.default_connection
        workspace: default
        username: admin
        password: admin
    odm:
        auto_mapping: true
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

you may try this
[symfony cmf fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001131/symfony-cmf-doctrine-phpcr-migrator-page-variable)

symfony-cmf had a lot trouble to begin with.

but i found a working one with linux and windows.
and you can use other than sqlite.
good luck.